# How to sort a vector in Rust?

Tags: sorting, rust

What is the currently recommended method for sorting values in a vector?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

A mutable slice of elements with a total ordering has a [`sort`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) method.

Because [`Vec<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) implements `DerefMut<[T]>`, you can call this method directly on a vector, so `vector.sort()` works.

Comment: What are the requirements for T type? I'm getting an error that says "Vec<MyType> does not implement any method in scope named 'sort'". I suspect this may be because I did not implement some traits for MyType, I have cmp::PartialEq and cmp::PartialOrd so far.

Comment: There's the `sort_by` method too which allows a completely custom predicate.

Comment: As the docs say, `self.sort()` == `self.sort_by(|a, b| a.cmp(b))`.

Comment: You can just call `.sort()` if the type `T` implements the `cmp::Ord` trait.

Comment: You could also take a look at `sort_unstable` it's bit faster, but could reorder "equal" elements

Answer (score 12):

To sort a vector `v`, *in most cases* [`v.sort()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) will be what you need.

If you want to apply a *custom* ordering rule, you can do that via [`v.sort_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by). That includes cases where you want to sort values that:

- don't implement [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) (such as [`f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html), most structs, etc);
- do implement [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html), but you want to apply a specific non-standard ordering rule.

Also note that `sort()` and `sort_by()` use a *stable* sorting algorithm (i.e., equal elements are not reordered). If you don't need a stable sort, you can use [`sort_unstable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable) / [`sort_unstable_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable_by), as those are generally a bit faster and use less memory.

Answer (score -2):

While the solutions proposed above can sort vectors of integers I had problems in sorting vectors of floats.

The simplest solution was to use the [quickersort crate](https://docs.rs/quickersort/3.0.0/quickersort/), which can also sort floats.
The quickersort crate can also sort other vectors of any type and also implements methods to sort using comparisons (sort_by).

Following is the Rust code:

```
extern crate quickersort;
//let's create the vector with the values
let mut vals = Vec::new();
vals.push(31.2);
vals.push(31.2);
vals.push(10.0);
vals.push(100.4);
vals.push(4.1);
quickersort::sort_floats(&mut vals[..]); // sort the vector
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a separate crate just to sort floats - for example, `v.sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal))` should work with floats. (Depending on what you want to do with NaNs in the array, you can write a more careful comparison function.)

Comment: *I had problems in sorting vectors of floats* —
 which is why there already entire questions and answers dedicated to that specific problem (https://stackoverflow.com/q/26489701/155423, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127209/155423).