# How to do a binary search on a Vec of floats?

Tags: rust

If you have a `Vec<u32>` you would use the [`slice::binary_search`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) method.

For reasons I don't understand, `f32` and `f64` do not implement `Ord`. Since the primitive types are from the standard library, you cannot implement `Ord` on them yourself, so it does not appear you can use this method.

How can you effectively do this?

Do I really have to wrap `f64` in a wrapper struct and implement `Ord` on it? It seems extremely painful to have to do this, and involves a great deal of `transmute` to cast blocks of data back and forth unsafely for effectively no reason.

Comment: `f32` and `f64` do not have a total ordering because NaN values are not equal to, greater than, nor less than any other floating point value according to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> for reasons I don't understand, f32 and f64 do not implement Ord.

Because [floating point is hard](http://floating-point-gui.de/)! The short version is that floating point numbers have a special value NaN - Not a Number. The IEEE spec for floating point numbers states that `1 < NaN`, `1 > NaN`, and `NaN == NaN` are all `false`.

[`Ord`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) says:

> Trait for types that form a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

This means that the comparisons need to have *totality*:

> a ≤ b or b ≤ a

but we just saw that floating points do not have this property.

So yes, you will need to create a wrapper type that somehow deals with comparing the [large number of NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19800415/155423). Maybe your case you can just assert that the float value is never NaN and then call out to the regular [`PartialOrd`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) trait. Here's an example:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(PartialEq,PartialOrd)]
struct NonNan(f64);

impl NonNan {
    fn new(val: f64) -> Option<NonNan> {
        if val.is_nan() {
            None
        } else {
            Some(NonNan(val))
        }
    }
}

impl Eq for NonNan {}

impl Ord for NonNan {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &NonNan) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<_> = [2.0, 1.0, 3.0].iter().map(|v| NonNan::new(*v).unwrap()).collect();
    v.sort();
    let r = v.binary_search(&NonNan::new(2.0).unwrap());
    println!("{:?}", r);
}
```

Comment: One of the slice extension methods is `binary_search_by`, which you could use. `f32`/`f64` implement `PartialOrd`, so if you know they can never be `NaN`, you can unwrap the result of `partial_cmp`: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.binary_search_by

Comment: One can use the [ordered_float](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float) or [ord_subset](https://crates.io/crates/ord_subset) crate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37144472/5189607

Answer (score 16):

One of the slice methods is [`binary_search_by`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by), which you could use. `f32`/`f64` implement `PartialOrd`, so if you know they can **never** be `NaN`, you can unwrap the result of `partial_cmp`:

```
fn main() {
    let values = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];
    let location = values.binary_search_by(|v| {
        v.partial_cmp(&3.14).expect("Couldn't compare values")
    });

    match location {
        Ok(i) => println!("Found at {}", i),
        Err(i) => println!("Not found, could be inserted at {}", i),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

[A built-in total-ordering comparison method for floats named `.total_cmp()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.total_cmp) is now stable, as of Rust 1.62.0. This implements that total ordering defined in IEEE 754, with every possible `f64` bit value being sorted distinctly, including positive and negative zero, and all of the possible NaNs.

Floats still won't implement `Ord`, so they won't be directly sortable, but the boilerplate has been cut down to a single line, without any external imports or chance of panicking:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<f64> = vec![2.0, 2.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.5];
    v.sort_by(f64::total_cmp);

    let target = 1.25;
    let result = v.binary_search_by(|probe| probe.total_cmp(&target));

    match result {
        Ok(index) => {
            println!("Found target {target} at index {index}.");
        }
        Err(index) => {
            println!("Did not find target {target} (expected index was {index}).");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that your floating point values will never be NaN, you can express this semantic with the wrappers in [decorum](https://docs.rs/decorum/0.1.3/decorum/). Specifically, the type [`Ordered`](https://docs.rs/decorum/0.1.3/decorum/type.Ordered.html) implements `Ord` and panics whenever the program tries to do something invalid:

```
use decorum::Ordered;

fn foo() {
    let ordered = Ordered<f32>::from_inner(10.);
    let normal = ordered.into()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/emerentius/ord_subset implements a `ord_subset_binary_search()` method that you can use for this.

from their README:

```
let mut s = [5.0, std::f64::NAN, 3.0, 2.0];
s.ord_subset_sort();
assert_eq!(&s[0..3], &[2.0, 3.0, 5.0]);
assert_eq!(s.ord_subset_binary_search(&5.0), Ok(2));

assert_eq!(s.iter().ord_subset_max(), Some(&5.0));
assert_eq!(s.iter().ord_subset_min(), Some(&2.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can derive `Ord` on your newtype using [nutype](https://github.com/greyblake/nutype) with `finite` validation without much boilerplate.
The `finite` validation excludes `NaN` and `Infinity`, what enables for nutype to derive `Ord` safely:

Here is an example:

```rs
use nutype::nutype;

#[nutype(
    validate(finite),
    derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)
)]
pub struct Float(f64);

fn main() {
    let raw_data = vec![1.1, 2.5, 0.1, 4.5];
    let mut data: Vec<Float> = raw_data
        .into_iter()
        .map(|val| Float::new(val).unwrap())
        .collect();

    data.sort();
    println!("data = {data:?}");

    let idx25 = data.binary_search(&Float::new(2.5).unwrap());
    println!("2.5 index = {idx25:?}");

    let idx36 = data.binary_search(&Float::new(3.6).unwrap());
    println!("3.6 index = {idx36:?}");
}
```

Output:

```
data = [Float(0.1), Float(1.1), Float(2.5), Float(4.5)]
2.5 index = Ok(2)
3.6 index = Err(3)
```

Note that `Float::new(val)` returns `Result`. Passing something like `Float::new(0.0/0.0)` would return an error.