# Is there any way to find the maximum value from an array of f32?

Tags: rust

I am trying to take the maximum value from an array of `f32`:

```
let v: [f32; 5] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0];    
let res = v.iter().max().unwrap();
```

But the trait `Ord` is not implemented for `f32` and I can't implement it because

> only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types [E0117]

I know about `PartialOrd`, but I cannot figure out how to use it in this situation.

I am sure that my collection is not empty and it does not contain `NaN` or infinity.

Is there any way to take max value from a f32 collection except by writing own wrappers or an imperative function like this?

```
fn maxf32(arr: &[f32; 5]) -> f32 {
    let mut res = arr[0];
    for &x in arr {
        if x > res {
            res = x;
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Comment: Also of interest is this [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3fg0xr/how_do_i_find_the_max_value_in_a_vecf64/)

Comment: @Shepmaster solution from this post works for me but looks a little ugly =(  Should i delete my question?

Comment: @Shepmaster One additional question - what about performance of our solution?

Comment: I wouldn't expect either solution to be drastically different from the other, performance-wise.

Comment: I just take NonNan struct from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28248065/1349525 add function val to unwrap float value and call it this way: v2.iter().map(|&x| NonNan::new(x).unwrap()).max().unwrap().val()

Comment: itertools' `fold1` can help, but it's a bit method-noisy too: `.iter().cloned().fold1(f32::max).unwrap()`

Comment: @bluss looks nice but my compiler (rustc 1.2.0) cannot find fold1 for iterator. But v2.iter().cloned().fold(v2[0], f32::max) works for me. If you want i can try to reopen question.

Comment: Right, it's not in std but in itertools, a separate crate.

Comment: @bluss I miss this. Everything seems to work. Thank you!