# How to find to order a vector of tuples based on the last value of the tuple, with rust?

Tags: rust

How to find to order a vector of tuples based on the last value (which is a `f64`) of the tuple, with rust? I have a big vector with tuples, so I'm looking for an efficient way to order this vector.

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut results = vec![
        ("a".to_string(), 50,  5.0),
        ("b".to_string(), 70, 4.0),
        ("c".to_string(), 40, 10.0)
    ];
}
```

Comment: just loop over the vector...

Comment: @Netwave Sorry, I've rephrased my question.

Comment: @Chris Not really, it's not related to tuples. Also the answer is related to integers.

Comment: You may find useful infomation, in particular about `sort_by` in that question and its answers.

Comment: This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707591/574531) on the linked duplicate explains what you need to do if you have types that aren't inherently sortable or if you otherwise need custom ordering rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by) and [`f64::partial_cmp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.partial_cmp) to order them:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut results = vec![
        ("a".to_string(), 50,  5.0),
        ("b".to_string(), 70, 4.0),
        ("c".to_string(), 40, 10.0)
    ];

    results.sort_by(|a, b| a.2.partial_cmp(&b.2).unwrap());
    
    println!("{:?}", results);
}
```

This will panic on values like `inf` or `NaN` since they cannot be ordered, but cases like those should be easy enough to handle outside of the closure if needed.