# Dedup piled-up mpsc channel messages

Tags: rust

When using a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html), let's say at a given moment we have the following messages in the queue for a given receiver:

```
abc
blah
abc
something
something
blah
something
```

Usually messages are processed like this:

```
let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel::<Msg>();
for msg in receiver {
   // Process a message...
}
```

What is the easiest way to de-duplicate messages that have already piled up?

Using the above example, I'd like to only process 3 (not 7) messages:

```
abc
blah
something
```

Note: After a message `abc` has been processed, it's fine to receive (and process) another message `abc` again in the future. The goal is to only de-duplicate messages that have already piled-up in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

Here is an example solution:

```
loop {
    let deduped_msgs : HashSet<Msg> = HashSet::from_iter(receiver.try_iter());
    for msg in deduped_msgs {
        // Process a message...                
    }
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
}
```

The above uses the non-blocking [try_iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.try_iter) method. I've added a short `sleep()` to avoid excessive pressure on the CPU.

### Solution 2

Here is a similar solution, as per Chayim's suggestions, that avoids the need for periodic checks every X milliseconds:

```
let mut deduped_msgs = HashSet::new();
loop {
    deduped_msgs.insert(receiver.recv().unwrap());
    deduped_msgs.extend(receiver.try_iter());               
    for msg in deduped_msgs.drain() {
        // Process a message... 
    }
}
```

### Order of processing

If the order in which messages are processed matters, [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) (alone) might not be the best option.

- To process messages in the order they arrived (only taking into account the first occurrence of each message), one could use [IndexSet](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html) for example.
- In some cases the natural order of messages might make more sense and then [BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) could be the simplest option.
- To apply some sort of a custom priority ordering, one could, for
  example, utilize a vector and [sort
  it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707591/15602349) via
  [sort_unstable_by](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable_by)
  or
  [sort_unstable_by_key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_unstable_by_key)
  (probably simpler to first dedup them with a `HashSet`, but another
  option might be to
  [dedup](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup)
  an already sorted vector).

Comment: Two things I would change: keeping the set between iterations to avoid excessive allocations, and using `recv()` instead of `sleep()`. Other than that I believe this is the best you can get.

Comment: [Like that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=30cf988e078c8aec925da3c73df1cc89).

Comment: Thanks @ChayimFriedman! I've updated my answer to include your suggestions as well.

Comment: An important note: this does not keep the order of received messages. If this is important, you can use [`IndexSet`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/set/struct.IndexSet.html).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's a good point. I've added some notes to my answer. Thanks!