# How do I get the minimum or maximum value of an iterator containing floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point, iterator, rust

I understand [why the floats don't have an implementation for `Ord`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26489701/155423) but that doesn't particularly help me when I want to be lazy and use iterators.

Is there a workaround or an easy way to take the minimum / min / min_by of an iterator containing floating point numbers?

I know one can sort (which is slow) or wrap it in another type and implement the needed trades (which is verbose) but I am hoping for something a little more elegant.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Floats have their own [`min`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.min) and [`max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.max) methods that handle NaN consistently, so you can fold over the iterator:

```
use std::f64;

fn main() {
    let x = [2.0, 1.0, -10.0, 5.0, f64::NAN];

    let min = x.iter().fold(f64::INFINITY, |a, &b| a.min(b));
    println!("{}", min);
}
```

Prints `-10`.

If you want different NaN handling, you can use `PartialOrd::partial_cmp`. For example, if you wish to propagate NaNs, fold with:

```
use std::f64;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    let x = [2.0, 1.0, -10.0, 5.0, f64::NAN];

    let min = x.iter().fold(f64::INFINITY, |a, &b| {
        match PartialOrd::partial_cmp(&a, &b) {
            None => f64::NAN,
            Some(Ordering::Less) => a,
            Some(_) => b,
        }
    });
    println!("{}", min);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you know your data does not contain NaNs, then assert that fact by unwrapping the comparison:

```
fn example(x: &[f64]) -> Option<f64> {
    x.iter()
        .cloned()
        .min_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).expect("Tried to compare a NaN"))
}
```

If your data *may* have NaNs, you need to handle that case specifically. One solution is to say that [all 16,777,214 NaN values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800415/why-does-ieee-754-reserve-so-many-nan-values) are equal to each other and are always greater than or less than other numbers:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn example(x: &[f64]) -> Option<f64> {
    x.iter()
        .cloned()
        .min_by(|a, b| {
            // all NaNs are greater than regular numbers
            match (a.is_nan(), b.is_nan()) {
                (true, true) => Ordering::Equal,
                (true, false) => Ordering::Greater,
                (false, true) => Ordering::Less,
                _ => a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap(),
            }
        })
}
```

There are numerous crates available that can be used to give you whichever semantics your code needs.

---

You should **not** use `partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal)` because it provides unstable results when NaNs are present, but it leads the reader into thinking that they are handled:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::f64;

fn example(x: &[f64]) -> Option<f64> {
    x.iter()
        .cloned()
        .min_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal))
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", example(&[f64::NAN, 1.0]));
    println!("{:?}", example(&[1.0, f64::NAN]));
}
```

```
Some(NaN)
Some(1.0)
```

Comment: The comparison function can be abbreviated to  `a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or_else(|| a.is_nan().cmp(&b.is_nan()))`, which is shorter, but probably not easier to read.

Answer (score 10):

[A built-in total-ordering comparison method for floats named `.total_cmp()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.total_cmp) is now stable, as of Rust 1.62.0. This implements that total ordering defined in IEEE 754, with every possible `f64` bit value being sorted distinctly, including positive and negative zero, and all of the possible NaNs. Be aware that some NaNs sort above Infinity, and some NaNs sort below -Infinity, so the "maximum" value may be confusing in the presence of NaN, but it will be consistent.

Floats still won't implement `Ord`, so they won't be directly sortable, but the boilerplate has been cut down to a single line, without any external imports or chance of panicking:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a: Vec<f64> = vec![2.0, 2.5, -0.5, 1.0, 1.5];
    
    let maximum = *a.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.total_cmp(b)).unwrap();
    println!("The maximum value was {maximum}.");

    a.sort_by(f64::total_cmp);
}
```

Comment: `max_by_key` expects a function that takes 1 argument, but `f64::total_cmp` takes two. So this code does not compile as provided I think.

Comment: I can confirm this code cannot compile, the right solution is `let maximum = *a.iter().max_by(|a, b| a.total_cmp(b)).unwrap();`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this?

```
fn main() {
    use std::cmp::Ordering;
    let mut x = [2.0, 1.0, -10.0, 5.0];
    x.sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap_or(Ordering::Equal));
    println!("min in x: {:?}", x);
}
```

One thing I struggled with is that `sort_by` mutates the vector in place so you can't use it in a chain directly.