# Simplest way to sort a vector by several fields, incl. floats (PartialOrd)

Tags: rust

I want to sort a vector of structs, by comparing several fields of the structs. Example:

```
my_vec.sort_unstable_by_key(|k| (k.a, k.b, k.c));
```

That looks perfect. However, types like `f32` and `f64` only implement `PartialOrd` and not `Ord` (due to their special `NaN` values). So if some of those fields in the structs are `f64` for example, I cannot use the method above.

I know I can get the job done in several ways, but I'd like to know what would be the simplest solution for cases like this?

Comment: Using the [ordered_float](https://docs.rs/ordered-float) crate with it's [`OrderedFloat`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/2.8.0/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html) newtype is probably the easiest way, albeit slightly verbose.

Comment: Use `sort_by` instead and follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50308360) to construct the sorting criteria closure.