# Alternative to f32 and f64 that implements core::cmp::Ord

Tags: rust

I want to implement a scoring function which returns float like values (but never NaN etc.) and find the minimum values of a list with [`min_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by). As `min_by` requires its values to implement `core::cmp::Ord`, I can't use `f32` and `f64` ([which don't have a total ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489701/in-rust-f64-and-f32-dont-implement-total-ordering-via-ord-trait-why-this-restr)).

**Is there any floating point alternative in the library implementing `core::cmp:Ord` and if not, how do I build an alternative that excludes non-real values?**

Comment: There is nothing in the standard library. Does [this answer about a wrapper type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28248065/155423) fit your goal?

Comment: @Shepmaster, does this type prevent its instantiation by other means than `NonNan::new`, i.e. can I be certain `cmp` never panics? (In any case, it fits my immediate needs. Thank you so far.)

Comment: Outside of the module that it defined in, you can only use the public construction methods, so yes. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate then.