# How to call `min` on a generic type that could be either an integer or float?

Tags: rust

What do I do when I want to call min on integers and floats? For example consider this:

```
fn foo<T>(v1: T, v2: T)
    where ???
{
   ....
   let new_min = min(v1, v2);
   ....
}
```

The problem is that [min](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.min.html) doesn't work for `f32`. There is [another min](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.min) for floats.

How would I solve this problem?

Comment: What result do you want when `foo` is passed one or more `NaN`s?

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't know, I guess the same way that `Float` handles Nans and Infs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own trait that defines the behavior of the various types:

```
trait Min {
    fn min(self, other: Self) -> Self;
}

impl Min for u8 {
    fn min(self, other: u8) -> u8 { ::std::cmp::min(self, other) }
}

impl Min for f32 {
    fn min(self, other: f32) -> f32 { f32::min(self, other) }
}

fn foo<T>(v1: T, v2: T)
    where T: Min
{
   let new_min = Min::min(v1, v2);
}
```

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247990/how-to-do-a-binary-search-on-a-vec-of-floats) in [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489701/in-rust-f64-and-f32-dont-implement-total-ordering-via-ord-trait-why-this-restr), floating point comparisons [are hard](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

There's no **one** answer to what the result of `min(NaN, 0.0)` should be, so it's up to you to decide. If you decide that `NaN` is less than or greater than all other numbers, great! Maybe it's equal to zero! Maybe you should assert that there will *never* be a `NaN`...

Comment: Note: it might be worth demonstrating how to implement `Min` automatically for any type implementing `Ord`; it would be simpler than enumerating all integral types.

Comment: @MatthieuM. won't we run into [conflicting trait implementations](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4722b115be2efd7b1a28fdc326e5d20d&version=stable&backtrace=0)? At least until specialization...

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. When the OP stated "doesn't work" I thought that `min` (and `Ord`) were not implemented for `f32`. Since they are, indeed you would need specialization...

Comment: Since specialization has been implemented — no, specialization won't solve the conflicting trait problem (as `f32: !Ord`), you additionally need [mutually exclusive traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1148). @MatthieuM.