# What's the most straightforward way to chain comparisons, yielding the first non-equal?

Tags: syntax, comparison, rust

It's quite common to compare data with precedence, for a struct which has multiple members which can be compared, or for a `sort_by` callback.

```
// Example of sorting a: Vec<[f64; 2]>, sort first by y, then x,
xy_coords.sort_by(
    |co_a, co_b| {
        let ord = co_a[1].cmp(&co_b[1]);
        if ord != std::cmp::Ordering::Equal {
            ord
        } else {
            co_a[0].cmp(&co_b[0])
        }
    }
);
```

Is there a more straightforward way to perform multiple `cmp` functions, where only the first non-equal result is returned?

Answer (score 6):

> perform multiple cmp functions, where only the first non-equal result is returned

That's basically how `Ord` is defined for tuples. Create a function that converts your type into a tuple and compare those:

```
fn main() {
    let mut xy_coords = vec![[1, 0], [-1, -1], [0, 1]];

    fn sort_key(coord: &[i32; 2]) -> (i32, i32) {
        (coord[1], coord[0])
    }

    xy_coords.sort_by(|a, b| {
        sort_key(a).cmp(&sort_key(b))
    });
}
```

Since that's common, there's a method just for it:

```
xy_coords.sort_by_key(sort_key);
```

It won't help your case, because [floating point doesn't implement `Ord`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26489701/155423).

One of many possibilities is to kill the program on `NaN`:

```
xy_coords.sort_by(|a, b| {
    sort_key(a).partial_cmp(&sort_key(b)).expect("Don't know how to handle NaN")
});
```

See also

- [Using max_by_key on a vector of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37127209/155423)
- [How to do a binary search on a Vec of floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28247990/155423)

---

> There are times when you may not want to create a large tuple to compare values which will be ignored because higher priority values will early-exit the comparison.

Stealing a page from [Guava's `ComparisonChain`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html), we can make a small builder that allows us to use closures to avoid extra work:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct OrdBuilder<T> {
    a: T,
    b: T,
    ordering: Ordering,
}

impl<T> OrdBuilder<T> {
    fn new(a: T, b: T) -> OrdBuilder<T> {
        OrdBuilder {
            a: a,
            b: b,
            ordering: Ordering::Equal,
        }
    }

    fn compare_with<F, V>(mut self, mut f: F) -> OrdBuilder<T>
        where F: for <'a> FnMut(&'a T) -> V,
              V: Ord,
    {
        if self.ordering == Ordering::Equal {
            self.ordering = f(&self.a).cmp(&f(&self.b));
        }
        self
    }

    fn finish(self) -> Ordering {
        self.ordering
    }
}
```

This can be used like

```
struct Thing {
    a: u8,
}

impl Thing {
    fn b(&self) -> u8 {
        println!("I'm slow!");
        42
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Thing { a: 0 };
    let b = Thing { a: 1 };

    let res = OrdBuilder::new(&a, &b)
        .compare_with(|x| x.a)
        .compare_with(|x| x.b())
        .finish();

    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Comment: This answer is good for the example in the question, but doesn't address the question directly. There are times when you may not want to create a large tuple to compare values which will be ignored because higher priority values will early-exit the comparison. Basically - there are times its reasonable to avoid creating a tuple for comparison, where the approach in the question still applies.

Comment: @ideasman42 *doesn't address the question directly* — that might be true *if* the question had **any** kind of comments about performance or avoiding creating things. The **question** was quite clear: *What's the most straightforward way to chain comparisons, yielding the first non-equal?* and it was answered pretty directly. You can't retroactively change the spirit of the question just because you didn't properly state what was important to you the first time around.

Comment: I should have made this more clear, and I appreciate your answer. The question does ask for a *"way to perform multiple cmp functions"*, I was interested in this aspect specifically - a way to keep the comparison logic under the control of the closure (in this example). Otherwise I would have asked a more general question about comparisons.